# Flutter null safety migration build fails - 'FirebaseFirestoreWeb.runTransaction' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-dependencies

We are trying to upgrade our flutter project to null safety migration using the following link https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide.

- dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety - Successful
- dart pub get - Successful
- Migrate your code by hand- https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide#migrating-by-hand - Successful
- dart migrate - Successful

After completion of above commands and trying to start app using **flutter run**

```
/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-2.6.18/lib/cloud_firestore_web.dart:101:14:    
Error: The method 'FirebaseFirestoreWeb.runTransaction' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method
'FirebaseFirestorePlatform.runTransaction'.
  Future<T?> runTransaction<T>(TransactionHandler<T> transactionHandler,

/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.7.5/lib/src/platform_interface
/platform_interface_firestore.dart:170:14: Context: This is the overridden method ('runTransaction').
  Future<T?> runTransaction<T>(TransactionHandler<T> transactionHandler,

/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-2.6.18/lib/cloud_firestore_web.dart:101:14:
Error: The method 'FirebaseFirestoreWeb.runTransaction' doesn't have the named parameter 'maxAttempts' of overridden method    
'FirebaseFirestorePlatform.runTransaction'.
  Future<T?> runTransaction<T>(TransactionHandler<T> transactionHandler,

Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             49.6s
Failed to compile application.
```

We tried resolving the issue by upgrading flutter as below - (https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9221)

```
flutter pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
Because project depends on cloud_firestore ^5.1.0 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `cloud_firestore: ^4.4.5` which is latest stable on current data.

> [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore)

Then do

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`
- check if there is any compile error

Comment: `flutter pub get`
Running "flutter pub get" in project...
Resolving dependencies... (8.7s)
Because no versions of cloud_firestore match >4.4.5 <5.0.0 and cloud_firestore 4.4.5 depends on firebase_core ^2.8.0,
cloud_firestore ^4.4.5 requires firebase_core ^2.8.0.
And because firebase_storage >=10.1.0 <11.0.1 depends on firebase_core ^1.10.0, cloud_firestore ^4.4.5 is incompatible with    
firebase_storage >=10.1.0 <11.0.1.
So, because project depends on both firebase_storage ^10.3.0 and cloud_firestore ^4.4.5, version solving failed.       
pub get failed

Comment: Remove these packages[store on temp file] and try to search each package is indicating and add the updated version based on pub.dev